# Can the TTreeView display more than 259 characters in a Row?

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I was wondering why the `TTreeView` cuts off my text at the 259th character.
I have already found some forums and website, where they say it is a limitation of Windows.
Does it also apply to the C++ Builder 2010?

And if it is, why is it possible to store more characters in the `TreeNode` property?

Comment: *Does it also apply to the C++ Builder 2010?* Yes, of course. It applies to any programming language that creates applications for Windows, using Windows controls. The length of the display of the string is limited to 260 (259 chars + a terminating null), probably because that is seen as the max conveniently readable, by the user. The storage (memory allocation) of the string does not need to be limited.

Comment: I was curious whether C++ Builder also utilizes Windows controls, as the help tab in C++ Builder consistently refers to the VCL ComCtrls

Comment: Yes, it does, as the answer below states.

Comment: @killa the `ComCtrls` unit implements components that wrap various [common UI controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/common-controls-intro) from the `comctrl32.dll` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering why the `TTreeView` cuts off my text at the 259th character.

Because that is simply how a standard Win32 [TreeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tree-view-control-reference) control works.  This is documented behavior on MSDN:

[TVITEMA structure (commctrl.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-tvitema)
[TVITEMW structure (commctrl.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-tvitemw)

> Note that although the tree-view control allows any length string to be stored as item text, **only the first 260 characters are displayed**.

If you need to display more characters, you will have to draw the TreeView nodes yourself using the `TTreeView::OnCustomDrawItem` or `TTreeView::OnAdvancedCustomDrawItem` event.

---

> I have already found some forums and website, where they say it is a limitation of Windows. Does it also apply to the C++ Builder 2010?

Yes, because the `TTreeView` component is just a wrapper for the standard Win32 [TreeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tree-view-control-reference) control.

---

> And if it is, why is it possible to store more characters in the TreeNode property?

Because the `TTreeNode::Text` property is just a plain `System::String`, so it can be as long as memory allows.  But when the `TTreeNode::Text` is applied to the underlying Win32 TreeView (in response to a [`TVN_GETDISPINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tvn-getdispinfo) notification), the `Text` is copied into whatever buffer the OS decides to receive the text into, and the OS displays only 260 characters from that buffer.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for a component that combines aspects of a `TreeView` and a `ListView`? I'm looking for a display that can accommodate up to 500 characters and provides functionality to show and hide individual nodes. Please note that I cannot use external libraries, and the application should be developed in C++ Builder 2010, preferably in C++

Comment: @killa "*I cannot use external libraries*" then you've ruled out every solution, unless you make your own custom control from scratch. There is no native component that merges TreeView and ListView functionalities, but there are 3rd party components that do, such as VirtualTreeView